# Unresolved Identifier for Table (Swift 2)

Tags: ios, swift2

I was trying to make a table show dates from a calendar in the cells but when I wrote the array it gave me the error of 'Unresolved Identifier for "Date"'

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class DatesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Properties

    var dates = [Date]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        func loadSampleDates() {

            let date1 = Date(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))!
            let date2 = Date(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))!
            let date3 = Date(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))!
            let date4 = Date(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))!

            dates += [date1, date2, date3, date4]

        }
```

The file is in the correct group, it is pointing to an existing table and cell, I am just unsure what else to check for. 
I will preface this by saying I am newer to Swift so I might just be simply missing an obvious mistake, but based on the iOS Developer site this seems to be the correct way to write this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` ***is*** an unresolved identifier (unless it's a separate class you wrote yourself) — you probably want to use `NSDate`:

```
 import UIKit

 class DatesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: Properties

dynamic var dates = [NSDate]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    func loadSampleDates() {

        let date1 = NSDate(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))
        let date2 = NSDate(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))
        let date3 = NSDate(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))
        let date4 = NSDate(print(CALENDAR_CLOCK))

        dates += [date1, date2, date3, date4]

    }
}}
```

Note that the NSDate print function will always return a result — it's not optional, so there's no need to use an `!` to force-unwrap it.

Comment: I should probably clarify, I am trying to fill a table with pre-set dates and times. When I try this code; the error is removed, but no content fills the table. Is this relevant to the NSDate or my own ineptitude with a new programming language?

Comment: If your interface is binding to the "dates" var, then it needs to be marked as "dynamic" -- I edited my answer above to show this. See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, the code itself works perfectly, thanks! I do have a follow-up but the original question itself has been answered.